# Debug IA-32 code on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: software-recommendation, catalina, development

I'm studying the [IA-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) assembly language and I'm operating on macOS Catalina 10.15.13. Right now I'm using vim as my editor and nasm for compiling the source.

Is there a software for debugging the assembly code? I need to see the registry status and values (with flags).

1. It doesn't matter if software have a Gui (it can be a console disassembler).
2. It shouldn't be a complete IDE (ex. Xcode, Clion, etc..)
3. With this software I need to see the memory status, the registry values (EAX,EBX,ECX,EIP etc..) and the flags (OF,ZR,PF,CF,etc...).

Comment: See [this Meta answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a hardware/software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Comment: @fsb thank you for your reply. I added some constraint to this post as suggested in the meta answer

Comment: How do you run your compiled code currently? What kind of research regarding tools did you already do?

Comment: I simply compile the code with NASM and gcc then I run it. I've tried out to use as debugger gcc (via console) and llvm but they are a little bit compless to use for a beginner.

Comment: `gdb` is the debugger of choice. Any debugger has a learning curve so you won't be able to get around this.